# Who invented the gradient?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I swear I've googled the hell out of this question and have come up with nothing.

Who is responsible for coming up with the gradient and why did they do so? In which work was it first described?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because better suited for [History of Science and Mathematics Stackexchange](http://hsm.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that existed. However, since that se is still in beta and isn't nearly as active, this question seems fair to post here.

Comment: You might have luck searching for that information in [Boyer's History of Calculus](https://archive.org/details/TheHistoryOfTheCalculusAndItsConceptualDevelopment), though I don't see it in the index right away.  Perhaps it is under a different name.  I would expect the concept to have been known by Newton.